# Why does Python not use all available system resources

Tags: python, loops

[This image shows that python is not using all available system resources.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Hobx.png)

I have written a code which has three nested for loops, each looping 1000 times. My question is that why is python not using all available system resources

```
    for i in range(1000):
        for j in range(1000):
            for k in range(1000):
                print(i,j,k)
```

Comment: Where is your code?

Comment: Why is any software not using all available system resources?

Comment: Python is single-threaded. Meaning that it uses only one core if you have multi-core cpu. Hence not all resources are used by loop. Although it may have threads Python uses global mutex (GIL) to block multiple threads from running same time on different cores.

Comment: Depending on your code it may also be waiting for the console to process whatever is being printed, slowing down the pure loop further that way…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python is single-hardware-threaded. Meaning that it uses only one core if you have [multi-core](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-core_processor) [CPU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_processing_unit).

Hence not all resources are used by loop, this may explain image.

E.g. if your have 4 cores with hyper threading meaning 2 hardware threads per core then python will use only 12% of whole CPU!

Although it may have threads Python uses global blocking mutex ([GIL](https://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock)) to block multiple threads from running same time on different cores, so Python threads are in a sence not parallel at all, they run sequentially interchanging each other for small portions of time.

Also due to console output loop may not be using as much as possible even from one core, try doing loop without printing.

Single-hardware-threading of Python may be overcome if you run multiple processes (different Pythons) same time, this can be easily done through [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html) standard Python's module.

Also parallel execution within one Python process is also possible if from different threads you're calling library's functions written in [C++](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B), then GIL is released, but pure python functions will block due to GIL.

But if you have single threaded pure python code then definitely only one core will be used at most, meaning not whole CPU.